# D3 - How to create appropriate JSON file for force-directed clusters graph

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to create a graph in d3.js  with a JSON file but I am not sure if the format of the file is readable.

This an example of the data:

```
{ "areaLabel": {
    "type": "uri",
    "value": "http://data.cso.ie/census-2011/classification/PR/P1"
  }
  ,
  "population": {
    "type": "typed-literal",
    "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int",
    "value": "2504814"
  }
},
```

This what I have done in http://jsfiddle.net/degzs/g6Ujg/79/

I just don't understand the format of the JSON file.

Comment: I would suggest that you start from an example like [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045). You can have a look at its JSON structure and what is done with the data.

Comment: arealabel = PR/P1, population = 2504814 on a y and x axis